# Android scaled Button not clickable

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I created a fragment which contains a FrameLayout containing a few buttons:

```
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/menu_view"
    android:layout_width="490dp"
    android:layout_height="490dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginRight="-200dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="-200dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-200dp"
    android:background="@drawable/menu_view_bg">

    <Button android:id="@+id/menu_btn1"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="185dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="185dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="107dp"
        android:background="@drawable/menu_btn_bg"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/menu_item0"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:text="@string/menu1"/>

    <Button android:id="@+id/menu_btn2"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/menu_btn_bg"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/menu_item1"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:text="@string/menu2"/>

        ...
    </FrameLayout>
```

In my fragment class, I scale the menu on a click on a Button outside of FrameLayout but when I try to click on buttons inside it, it won't work. If I don't scale the view at start, it works.

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    FrameLayout menuView = (FrameLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.menu_view);
    menuView.setScaleX(0.1f);
    menuView.setScaleY(0.1f);

    Button btn = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.menu_main_btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            toggleMenu();
        }
    });

    Button hotelBtn = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.menu_btn2);
    hotelBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("fef", "onClick: dodkoz");
        }
    });
}
```

Specifically, if I comment these two lines, it will work (I set the onclick in my fragment class, not in XML):

```
menuView.setScaleX(0.1f);
menuView.setScaleY(0.1f);
```

I guess this has something to do with hit area but I can't find what exactly. I'm fairly new to Android dev so I haven't come up with a workaround. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use this.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
      View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourframelayout, container, false);

      Button btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.menu_main_btn);
      btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
             // toggleMenu();
          }
      });

      Button hotelBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.menu_btn2);
      hotelBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              Log.d("fef", "onClick: dodkoz");
          }
      });
}
```

Comment: Where should I use this? In Activity or Fragment class?

Comment: you should keep in fragment class remove yours keep mine

Comment: Alright I did that but it didn't change anything. If I scale menuView to 0.1f in onCreateView() and scale it to 1f later, buttons inside menuView still won't receive click.